# Unwanted word behind my title in SERP

Tags: tags, seo, google

Can anyone here help me about my title problem in google?

My title in google result page do not exact match with my title tag. If you search with keyword "itclax furidacchi" in google, my title there is a anime word.
Im not use anime word in my title. I dont know what must i do again, i inspect element doesnt work, nothing anime word in my element site.!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y0RW.png)

Comment: Hey Yuyun, I don't think anyone here can help you with this question. You should try on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com exchange. They deal with seo related stuff.

Comment: OK i will do that